# Why declare a reference to an instance of a final class as being final? 

Tags: java, oop, immutability, final

What is significance of second line :

```
public final class A {}
final A obj1=new A();
```

If `A` is a already immutable, why would one possibly want to make `obj1` final? (just to make it stick to a unique memory reference? ).

Comment: Nothing in you sample code implies immutability.

Answer (score 15):

`final` in the first line means that the object is closed for extension...i.e. you can't subclass it.

`final` in the second line means you can't reassign the variable.

Answer (score 2):

First, `A` is not immutable of you just declare it `final`.

Then, final variables cannot be changed. If `obj1` is a field this enforces mutability (unlike the `final class`).

If it is a local variable it means you can safely use it in anonymous classes (otherwise the compiler can't be sure it won't get change sometimes before/while the anonymous class body is executed)